# Android studio fail to build react native project in Windows Os

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I am having a windows machine and am not able to build react native projects from android studio.

Comand use to create this project

"**npx react-native init**" myProject from powershell

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Initialization script 'C:\Users\ravi_\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling68.gradle'
> - What went wrong: Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\ravi_\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling68.gradle'.
>
> > startup failed:   General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60      at
> > groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:196)      at
> > groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:177)      at
> > groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:163)      at
> > groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:284)      at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:57)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:44)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveNonArrayType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:79)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:70)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.MemberSignatureParser.createMethodNode(MemberSignatureParser.java:57)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode$2.get(DecompiledClassNode.java:234)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode$2.get(DecompiledClassNode.java:231)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.createMethodNode(DecompiledClassNode.java:242)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitMembers(DecompiledClassNode.java:199)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(DecompiledClassNode.java:122)
> > at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:912)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.tryFindPossibleMethod(ClassNode.java:1280)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:252)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:113)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:142)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:110)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:121)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:53)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticImportVisitor.java:89)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:128)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1099)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:54)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitClass(StaticImportVisitor.java:83)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:708)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1084)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:640)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:618)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:595)
> > at
> > groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:401)
> > at
> > groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$300(GroovyClassLoader.java:89)
> > at
> > groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:341)
> > at
> > groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:338)
> > at
> > org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)
> > at
> > groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:336)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:95)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler$2.run(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:54)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:51)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:190)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:170)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:211)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:194)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:100)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:86)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:139)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:89)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:43)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:103)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
> > at
> > org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:126)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:116)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.getOrCompile(CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.java:50)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.java:50)
> > at
> > org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:49)
> > at
> > org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:110)
> > at
> > org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> > at
> > org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
> > at
> > org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
> > at
> > org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
> > at
> > org.gradle.configuration.DefaultInitScriptProcessor.process(DefaultInitScriptProcessor.java:50)
> > at
> > org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler$1.run(InitScriptHandler.java:56)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> > at
> > java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> > at
> > java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> > at
> > org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
> > at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
>
> 1 error
>
> at
> org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)
> ... 155 more
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 129ms

It is giving an error if I run via Powershell with **yarn android**

> BUILD FAILED in 1s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.    Error: Command
> failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Settings file 'B:\workA\react-native\splash\android\settings.gradle'
> - What went wrong: Could not compile settings file 'B:\workA\react-native\splash\android\settings.gradle'.
>
> > startup failed:   General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major
> version 60

Answer (score 0):

Step to run react-native on windows os

1)Open the react-native android project in the android studio

2)Build the project successfully and run it from the android studio

3)open your project folder and run 'npx react-native start'

This runs the project if you get a red screen telling you that the server does not found then

1)Add 'android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ' line in manifest

2)adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 type this in CMD or powershell

Now again try to run the project or reload using 'R' on terminal

I have found that the android emulator works out of the box. For an external device connected, you can use reverse TCP to make sure that the device can find the server.